# Installed module not found in electron js

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, monorepo

I want to contribute to an open source project called [Joplin](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin). But I am not able to setup the development environment.

I have followed the setup instructions as said [here](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin/blob/dev/BUILD.md#required-dependencies) . Everything get installed but and when I launch the application in `packages/app-desktop` by running `npm run start`(it's build with electron.js) , the application get started but logs this error in the console, due to this error UI is not loaded:
[image]

I have checked that module `@joplin/fork-htmlparser2` has correctly installed by running `npm list @joplin/fork-htmlparser2` command
[image]

I do not understand why the error logs say cannot find module `@joplin/fork-htmlparser2` since the npm command is saying it's installed.

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04,
Node: v16.0.0,
Npm:7.10.0,

Comment: Read the error message again. It doesn't say it can't find the _module_, it says it can't find the _file `lib/index.js` inside of the module_ and asks you to verify that the module's `package.json` has a `main` property that points to an existing file. Apparently it currently points to `lib/index.js` which doesn't exist.

Comment: According to your `npm ls` output, you aren't using packages from npm. My suspicion is now that you copied source code from GitHub instead of the npm registry, but didn't build the code as the developer would normally have done before publishing to npm, so the build output doesn't exist (there is probably a `src` folder but no `lib` for that reason).